# Javafx can not insert multi data into tableview

Tags: javafx, insert, tableview, scenebuilder

I have a project that need show data on javafx's tableview. The problem is: If there is one data in entry, it can show on tableview. But I would like to add multi data to list, but I do not know how. Where should I edit?

```
public void SelectOKAction(ActionEvent event) {

    String searchStr=select_text.getText();
    if(searchStr==null||searchStr.trim().equals("")){
        AlertBox.display("Wrong", "Please enter entry's name");
        return;
    }
    Entry entry=entryList.search(searchStr);
    if(entry==null){//NOT FOOUND
        AlertBox.display("Wrong", "Entry not exists!");
    }
    //show data in table
    OrderedList l=new OrderedLinkedList();
    l.add(entry);
    showDataInTable(l);

}
```

Insert data to tableview:

```
private void showDataInTable(OrderedList entryList){
    ObservableList<Entry> list = FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    for(int i=0;i<entryList.size();i++){
        Entry entry=entryList.get(i);
        Class<? extends Entry> clz=entry.getClass();
        if(Untils.checkField(clz, "journal")){
            Col_Journal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("journal"));
        }
        if(Untils.checkField(clz, "booktitle")){
            Col_Booktitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("booktitle"));
        }
        if(Untils.checkField(clz, "author")){
            Col_Author.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("author_str"));
        }
        if(Untils.checkField(clz, "editor")){
            Col_Editor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("editor"));
        }

        Col_BKey.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("name"));
        Col_Title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("title"));
        Col_Year.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("year"));
        Col_EntryType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("entryType"));

        list.add(entry);            
    }
    table_id.setItems(list);


}
```

Comment: "It will have error". What error?

Comment: @James_D I can not show multi entry in tableview, but it can show on tableview with one entry in list.

Comment: sorry @James_D it do not have error. I just do not know how to insert multi data to table view.

Comment: Instead of `table_id.setItems(list)` try `table_id.getItems().addAll(list)`. Though I don't really understand your code - it seems to rely on a lot of proprietary classes. I don't know why you are setting cell value factories in a loop, you only need to do that once. And you can't add anything to an empty list (an empty list is one that is always empty; it will throw exceptions if you try to add to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many of those lines are supposed to stay outside the loop

```
private void showDataInTable(OrderedList entryList){
    ObservableList<Entry> list = FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    for(int i=0;i<entryList.size();i++){
        Entry entry=entryList.get(i);
        list.add(entry);
    }

    Col_Journal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("journal"));
    Col_Booktitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("booktitle"));
    Col_Author.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("author_str"));
    Col_Editor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("editor"));
    Col_BKey.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("name"));
    Col_Title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("title"));
    Col_Year.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("year"));
    Col_EntryType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entry, String>("entryType"));

    table_id.setItems(list);

}
```

I have removed `checkField`, you don't need that many similar classes, you can use one big `Entry` class that looks similar to this and leave unused fields blank

```
public class Entry {

    private SimpleStringProperty journal = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty booktitle = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty author_str = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty editor = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty year = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty entryType = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Entry(String Sjournal, String Sbooktitle, String Sauthor_str, String Seditor, String Sname, String Stitle, String Syear, String SentryType){
        journal.set(Sjournal);
        booktitle.set(Sbooktitle);
        author_str.set(Sauthor_str);
        editor.set(Seditor);
        name.set(Sname);
        title.set(Stitle);
        year.set(Syear);
        entryType.set(SentryType);
    }

}
```